# How to prevent auto open in bootstrap date picker?

Tags: javascript

I'm using bootstrap datepicker in my application which is dynamically built.
the dialog box is automatically open when the form is submitted with the data.

Below is my code:

JSP:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" id="Q${qaf.id}_${qaf.type}" name="${qaf.id}" type="text" value="${fn:escapeXml(qaf.answerValue[0])}"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
</div>
```

Javascript::

```
$(function (event) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true            
    });  
});
```

Help me out to prevent the auto open .

I appreciate your help! Thanks in advance...

Comment: auto open when form submitting without the data*

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "autoApply": true,
            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }
        });
    });
```

use this

Comment: I tried using the above but the dialog box is not getting opened even on click

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepicker" ValidationGroup="G1" ID="datepick" placeholder="date"  />

Comment: I'm using JSP(Html)